# Как сделать чтобы при печати страницы она ресайзилась

Tags: html, css, print

При разработке столкнулся с такой проблемой: клиент хочет чтобы при печати страницы она ресайзилась под нужный размер. Media print не интересует, нужна полная копия.. В интернете встречал, что есть как сайты с media print, так и те, у которых автоматом ресайз.

Делал на bootstrap, про его media print знаю. Cms битрикс, если это на что-то влияет. При печати подцепляет стили из разрешения до 768.

Как это выполнить?

Answer (score 0):

media print это как раз ваш выбор (один из самых удачных подходов к этой задаче), либо как вариант вы можете использовать [onbeforeprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint) в JS, но [поддержка](https://caniuse.com/#feat=beforeafterprint) у него не самая удачная. В [случае с media](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) она намного удачнее.

Comment: тогда почему некоторые сайты автоматом подстраиваются при печати, а для некоторых необходимо использование media?